# YouTube app not working with squid. What urls to bump exclude?

Tags: squid, android, opnsense

I have squid running with SSL Bump. The rest of the squid settings are basically defaults. I can access YouTube just fine from a browser but the android app is not working.  I've already excluded these from SSL Bump with no success.

- youtube.com
- [www.youtube.com](http://www.youtube.com)
- m.youtube.com
- ytimg.com
- s.ytimg.com
- ytimg.l.google.com
- youtube.l.google.com
- i.google.com
- googlevideo.com
- youtu.be
- yt.be

Where can I find logs of what urls are trying to be reached?